# How creating forcefsck file triggers file system check on reboot?

Tags: filesystems, fsck

What is the significance of the file `/forcefsck`? I understand by creating this file the file system check is enforced during the next reboot. But how does this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example in the case of Debian it's in this init script: `/etc/init.d/checkfs.sh` (and `/etc/init.d/checkroot.sh`, and any of their symbolic links):

```
...
if [ -f /forcefsck ] || grep -s -w -i "forcefsck" /proc/cmdline
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This pointed me in the right direction. I appreciate it:)